# Getting JSON from an API with AJAX

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I tried getting json data from an "api" with AJAX. I succesfully done it with plain JavaScript but now I have a problem doing the same with Jquery.

My HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="ajax()">Wijzig Content</button>
    <input type="text" name="iets" value="nog iets">
    <br><br>
    <div id="myDiv">Let AJAX change this text</div>
```

The array that my api gives:

```
$Names = [["vnaam"=>"name1","tv"=>"van","anaam"=>"piet"],
        ["vnaam"=>"name2","tv"=>"van","anaam"=>"piet"],
        ["vnaam"=>"name3 slang","tv"=>"van","anaam"=>"piet"]];
```

And the JQuery which doesn't work yet:

```
function ajax(){
            $.get( "api.php?action=all", function( data ) {
                console.log(data.vnaam);
              $( "#myDiv" )
                .append( "naam: " + data.vnaam )
                .append( "tussenvoegsel: " + data.tv )
                .append( "achternaam: " + data.anaam );
            }, "json" );};
```

When I `console.log(data)` it returns the whole array. But when I type `console.log(data.vnaam)` it doesn't. What am I not seeing/doing wrong?

Comment: `data` is a variable scoped to that function.  It will not exist outside of it for you to reference in your console.  Since `data` is an array, you cannot do `data.vnaam`.  You will have to loop over it or in some manner reference each one with `data[indexNumber].vnaam`

Comment: Isn't your data an array, do you mean data[0].vnaam?

Comment: I forget the index, must have overlooked that. Could you write that in an answer so I can close this post?